# how to delete objects created in main in cpp

Tags: c++, visual-c++

when I run the code i get "b fn
destruct b
destruct a" and runtime error. the problem is deleting any one object say  object of b invokes destructor of class a as well so when the other delete try to do delete of the object it hits runtime error, so anyone kindly suggest, how can we fix this?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
class a
{
    public:
    virtual void f(){cout<<"a fn"<<endl;};
    virtual ~a(){cout<<"destruct a"<<endl;};
};

class b: public a
{
    public:
    void f(){cout<<"b fn"<<endl;};
    ~b(){cout<<"destruct b"<<endl;};
};

int main() {
    class a *aa = new a;
    class b *bb = new b;
    aa = bb;

    aa->f();

    delete aa;
    delete bb;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: ‘*how can we fix this?*’ Don't use pointers.

Comment: wtf.. you seem really confused - what does this have to do with inheritance and destructors? You clearly have a double-free and a memory leak ... nothing more complicated than that... _"how can we fix this"_ Don't do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your program behaviour is undefined.

Setting `aa = bb;` is disastrous:

1. You will attempt to delete the same object twice. That's undefined behaviour.
2. You'll never `delete` the original `aa`. That's a memory leak.

Remove that line and all will be well. If you want to test polymorphism then you *could* write

`class/*actually, not required*/ a *bb = new b;`

Answer (score 1):

With

```
class a *aa = new a;
class b *bb = new b;
aa = bb;
```

you no longer have reference to `new a`

so

```
delete aa; // delete 'new b'
delete bb; // delete 'new b' a second time
```

double delete the same pointer.

Answer (score 0):

Remove this

```
aa = bb;
```

and you will get **output**

```
a fn
destruct a
destruct b
destruct a
```

Success